# understanding where clauses entries

Tags: mysql, sql

Newbie in sql.
I am going thru multiple choice questions....and I am not able to figure out the right answer.

So basically if i have a where clause

```
where foo LIKE '%a\_%b' cannot display
1) a_b
2) a_%b
3) ab
4) abb
```

What are all these symbols

Answer (score 0):

You are using symbol in brackets like this

```
 where foo LIKE '%a[%]b'

1) a[_]b
2) a[_%]b
```

Comment: So the right answer would be.. I am totally confused with these notation? :(